# Tkinter Notebook loads tabs slow sometimes

Tags: python, tkinter

Sometimes when I change the tab of a notebook and then get rid of the tab the notebook will take a large amount of time for it to load the contents. I have attached code and videos. I cannot figure out how to fix it. I have tried making it select the tab when a tab is closed to make it go faster but nothing seems to work.

Minimum Reproducible example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import random
window = Tk()
s = Style(window)
s.theme_use("clam")
notebook = Notebook()
notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
index = 0
def add_tab(event=None):
    global index
    frame = Text(notebook)
    frame.insert("1.0", "This is text {}".format(index))
    notebook.add(frame, text="Hello {}".format(index))
    index += 1
    notebook.select(frame)
def delete_tab(event=None):
    if len(notebook.tabs())>1:
        index = notebook.index("current")
        notebook.forget(notebook.select())
        if len(notebook.tabs())>index:
            notebook.select(index)
def change_tab(event=None, index=None):
    if index==None:
        number = int(event.keysym)-1
    else:
        number = index
    if len(notebook.tabs()) > number:
        notebook.select(number)
add_tab_btn = Button(window, text="Add Tab", command=add_tab)
add_tab_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)
delete_tab_btn = Button(window, text="Delete Tab", command=delete_tab)
delete_tab_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)
def show_issue(event=None):
    add_tab()
    add_tab()
    #Change tabs 20 times with random indexes in the range of the tab count
    tab_count = len(notebook.tabs())
    for i in range(20):
        change_tab(index=int(random.randint(0, tab_count-1)))
    delete_tab()
show_error_btn = Button(window, text="Show Error", command=show_issue)
show_error_btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)
window.bind("<Command-Key-1>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-2>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-3>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-4>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-5>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-6>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-7>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-8>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-Key-9>", change_tab)
window.bind("<Command-t>", add_tab)
for i in range(5):
    add_tab()
window.mainloop()
```

[image: First Gif]

[image: Second Gif]

Note:

This is a Mac specific issue (though I have been told by some Windows users that they've had it) from testing I have done. I *could* make a custom `Notebook` but that poses separate issues.

Update: I have decided to make a better `Notebook` widget [here](https://github.com/Moosems/bazingo)

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you speak about. Maybe it's not a problem of tkinter but of the system it runs on which takes sometimes all the computing power away from Python for some CPU time consuming processes?

Comment: @Claudio I wrote some extra code that I will update the question with that gave me the error

Comment: @Claudio did you get the same error?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you speak about with the current code given in the question ( Python 3.9, Linux Mint 18).

Comment: @Claudio That's because its a Mac specific issue

Comment: @Claudio No, I never solved the problem and I am such a perfectionist that after I failed multiple times to fix it I just put the project on the backburner. I've come back to the project but I'm still infuriated at how I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Thats actually the funny part. I am trying to write a code editor (admittedly yes its in Python but I have reasons) and I want everything to be perfect in what comes prepackaged and then through extensions can become perfect for the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253040/discussion-between-claudio-and-trck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar problem on a Mac. In my case I noticed that the tabs were not so much updating slowly as they were not updating until the mouse moved over the notebook's content in that tab. Simply binding the NotebookTabChanged event to `update_idletasks()` fixed my issue. Hope this helps someone.

`window.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', lambda event: self.update_idletasks())`